# Command not found “dotnet”

Tags: .net, macos, terminal, radzen

so I have a Macbook Air M1 2020 version, im a student and I need to use Radzen for a project at university, inside Radzen to create an APP I need to install .Net 6.0, I can install it easily, but then Radzen doesn't create the app because for Radzen the .net is not installed yet, but I can find .net on /usr/local/share, so dotnet is installed, I saw some stuff online to try and fix this but the guys tell to write dotnet on terminal, and it was supposed to tell that it was installed, but in my case it just says 'command not found' can someone try to help me please? If you don't understand something let me know and I will try to explain better.

[image: Terminal_DOTNET]

Comment: Not enough here to diagnose. Perhaps show us output of `ls -l /usr/local/share/dotnet`? Also, if there are questions that you reference, perhaps you can share the links to them so that we don't repeat ourselves.

Comment: @Rob when I run that on terminal it responds "total 0"

Comment: I’m sorry, I thought you said that you had found it there. I was just asking for more details (the `ls -l`) of whatever you had found…